# Is there a way to remove all roles from a user that have a specific subrole in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, security, roles

I am using the FosUserBundle which provides the function where you can remove roles.

```
$user->removeRole("ROLE_SUBSCRIBER_BASIC")
```

This is nice and all, but my main problem is that I would like to remove the role by a specific subrole. My hierarchy in security.yml looks like this:

```
    ROLE_SUBSCRIBER: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUBSCRIBER_MONTHLY: [ROLE_SUBSCRIBER]
    ROLE_SUBSCRIBER_YEARLY: [ROLE_SUBSCRIBER]
    ROLE_SUBSCRIBER_BASIC:  [ROLE_SUBSCRIBER]
    ROLE_PRIVILEGE_PLUS: [ROLE_SUBSCRIBER]
    ROLE_SUBSCRIBER_PLUS:  [ROLE_PRIVILEGE_PLUS]
    ROLE_SUBSCRIBER_EXTRA:  [ROLE_PRIVILEGE_PLUS]
```

As you can see a PLUS, EXTRA and BASIC subscriber all are subscribers so i gave them a subrole "ROLE_SUBSCRIBER".
In my unsubscribe function, I would like to remove the current subscriber role, without having to use if else loops like this:

```
 public function unsubscribe(User $user)
    {
    if($user->hasRole("ROLE_SUBSCRIBER_BASIC")){
        $user->removeRole("ROLE_SUBSCRIBER_BASIC");
    }
    if($user->hasRole("ROLE_SUBSCRIBER_PLUS")){
        $user->removeRole("ROLE_SUBSCRIBER_PLUS");
    }
    if($user->hasRole("ROLE_SUBSCRIBER_EXTRA")){
        $user->removeRole("ROLE_SUBSCRIBER_EXTRA");
    }
```

...
        }

This if/else loops does its job, but think about the future. What if my boss wants there to be more subscriber roles, then I would have to edit this function every single time and add another IF. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Like by deleting the role by subrole.

```
$user->removeRole("ROLE_SUBSCRIBER")
```

This way it would remove ROLE_SUBSCRIBER_EXTRA,ROLE_SUBSCRIBER_BASIC, ...MONTHLY, ...YEARLY or ...PLUS automatically, without me having to check what kind of subscription the user currently has!?

Comment: But you always want to keep monthly and yearly subscribers?

Comment: @Cerad Good one, i didn't add that in my post. I will edit this. I would like to remove those too! All of them should be gone after I unsubscribe

Comment: It is possible to inject the role hierarchy object and then automatically remove the roles.  Kind of a pain.  I'd save it until you actually have a change to make.  I don't think you really need to check hasRole before calling removeRole.  Pretty sure removeRole will just do nothing if the user does not actually have the role.  So may just a test for ROLE_SUBSCRIBER followed by a set of remove roles.

Comment: Thank you. I will remove those if checks, they dont seem to be necessary indeed

Comment: Since you have a nice pattern of `ROLE_SUBSCRIBER_xxx`, then it seems you could just loop over all roles of the user and of there is a pattern match (preg_match) then remove that role. No need for future code changes as long as you follow that subscriber pattern.

Comment: @ehymel That's a good idea too! I think this will be faster

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
const KEEP_ROLES = ['ROLE_ADMIN'];

$rolesToRemove = array_diff($user->getRoles(), KEEP_ROLES);

foreach ($rolesToRemove as $role) {
   $user->removeRole($role);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However this wouldn't work in my case since the user already has other roles like "ROLE_ADMIN" or something else. I wouldn't want to remove those

Comment: In that case, the logic that will remove the roles needs to know what roles do you want to keep. I just updated my answer.